# Convert varchar to hexadecimal in sql server

Tags: sql-server, hive

I want a function to convert a varchar to hexadecimal in sql server. Please help me.

P.S. I will use unhex() in Hive to try to get the original value back. This is because my data contains special characters and backslash and the HIVE external table does not recognise it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use `CONVERT` function:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 'myText')
```

Output:

```
0x6D7954657874
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
select try_convert(varbinary,varcharcolumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use try_convert to avoid errors when the conversion fails.. Also, varbinary(n) is a better alternative to varbinary(max) as the latter would set the page size to 2GB, which might be excessive.

Hope this helps!